# При 1024пх из-за бургера появляется горизонтальный скролл! Как исправить?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

При 1024пх и ниже из-за бургера появляется горизонтальный скролл! Как исправить?
https://roderen.github.io/onegin/

Comment: Обернуть всё содержимое и обёртке задать `overflow: hidden` вместо `body`. Потому что от `body` это свойство переназначается вьюпорту и поэтому не работает. Или сделать какую-то обёртку только для меню. Или сделать расширение самого меню от правого края вместо выезжания из-за пределов экрана.

Comment: Не помог ни один вариант(
Пробовал сделать width: 0; а при нажатии на кнопку, для меню ставится width: 430px; Но столкнулся с новой проблемой, что видно пока выезжает/заезжает меню, то строки в нём прыгают